# Lossless quarter wavelength transmission lines

Tags: transmission-line, input-impedance, characteristic-impedance

so my lecturer released a past paper with the answers and I have no idea how he got the answer to this question. Please could someone explain it to me? Thanks.

The question is:
A lossless quarter-wavelength transmission line is terminated by a load of 100+j50
Ω at one end. The input impedance seen at the other end is 100-j50 Ω. What is the characteristic impedance of the quarter-wavelength transmission line?

The answer is meant to be 112Ω

Comment: In order to perform Conjugate matching of Zin to Zout the Zo must be the RMS result of \$Z_o=(x^2+y^2)^{0.5}\$  for Zin=x+jy

Comment: http://amanogawa.com/transmission.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

It's called a quarter wave impedance transformer and is covered thoroughly and extensively (and maybe quite beautifully) by [this wiki site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarter-wave_impedance_transformer). That site contains this formula: -

$$\dfrac{Z_{IN}}{Z_0}=\dfrac{Z_0}{Z_L}$$

If you rearrange that formula and solve for \$Z_0\$ you'll get the answer 111.803 Ω

Comment: Thank you so much, I was looking at the other formula for the characteristic impedance, hence why it didn't make sense. Much appreciated!